# Executing a PostgreSQL Database Package's Function within C# code using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, pgadmin, postgres-plus

I am wondering if anyone knows how exactly to go about calling a Package's function within C# code(within a repository class), specifically using LINQ?  I have created a package with the help of EDB Postgres documentation.  All it does is query a particular database table for the latest value in a particular column.  I created and saved the Package into the schema that the table is a part of, but not to the table itself (if that makes sense).  What exactly is the process to access a Package's function using LINQ or perhaps another means?  EDB Postgres documentation has no examples like this, and similar answers online are for very different circumstances and I was unable to modify them to fit my needs.

Comment: There are a few ways 1) Use Entity 2) Use SQL Client class and fill DataTable.  You can then query DataTable. 3) Raw SQL which can call a stored procedure.

Comment: How exactly are you defining a package in Postgres. Other database managers, especially Oracle, have a Package object that houses other database objects (procedures, functions, etc). **Postgres however does not support such packages.**

Comment: @Belayer I did it through pgadmin using information from this link:  https://www.enterprisedb.com/docs/epas/14/epas_compat_sql/27_create_package_body  It says it worked (I see my function within the Packages tab of the schema) but I have no idea how to call it.

Comment: Ok, then this is not a question about PostgreSQL. I have changed the tags accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, seems like the package and its function can alternatively be called by using the DbFunctionCall() method, which takes in a schemaName, functionName, and optional functionName parameters (in case anyone runs into a similar issue).